# Cannot handle numeric attribute weka svm

Tags: java, weka, svm, libsvm

I have been trying to use MISVM of Standford Weka. But I keep getting the Error

`weka.classifiers.mi.MISVM: Cannot handle numeric attributes!`

**My Training Set File(file.arff)**

```
@relation 'SpamDetectionTrainingSet'
@attribute 'checkin' real
@attribute 'tips' real
@attribute 'badges' real
@attribute 'friends' real
@attribute 'mayors' real
@attribute 'lists' real
@attribute 'target' {'spam','nonspam'}
@data
1165,36,1,1,4,47,nonspam
8521,492,620,7,74,144,nonspam
5408,189,306,0,27,121,nonspam
0,43,319,0,0,0,spam
```

I have seen the solutions of previous questions. One Main point, I observed from them was to keep the `target attribute` nominal. My target attributes are nominal only

**My SOURCE CODE**

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.Utils;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSink;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
public class SVM 
{
    /* Read the Data in ARFF format */
    DataSource train,unknown,test;
    Instances trainData,unknownData;
    public SVM()
    {
        try {
            /* Loading the Data */
            train       = new DataSource("/home/hduser/file.arff");
            trainData   = train.getDataSet();
            trainData.setClassIndex(trainData.numAttributes()-1);

            /* Set Option for SVM Algorithm */
            String[] opt = Utils.splitOptions("-N 1 -D");

            /*Training */
            weka.classifiers.mi.MISVM rf = new weka.classifiers.mi.MISVM();

            rf.setOptions(opt);
            System.out.println(rf.getFilterType());

            rf.buildClassifier(trainData);

            /* Classify Users */
            unknown     = new DataSource("/home/hduser/fileTest1.arff");
            unknownData = unknown.getDataSet();
            unknownData.setClassIndex(unknownData.numAttributes()-1);

            Instances copy = new Instances(unknownData);

            for(int i=0;i<unknownData.numInstances();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello ");
                double value = rf.classifyInstance(unknownData.instance(i));
                copy.instance(i).setClassValue(value);
            }

            DataSink.write("/home/hduser/output1.arff", copy);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SVM r = new SVM();
    }
}
```

**COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE :**

```
weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.mi.MISVM: Cannot handle numeric attributes!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:954)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:869)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1085)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1023)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
    at weka.classifiers.mi.MISVM.buildClassifier(MISVM.java:607)
    at SVM.<init>(SVM.java:28)
    at SVM.main(SVM.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the file.arff:

```
@data
1165,36,1,1,4,47,nonspam
8521,492,620,7,74,144,nonspam
5408,189,306,0,27,121,nonspam
0,43,319,0,0,0,spam
```

There cannot be numeric value.

Change dataset, or change classifier